Windows 11 VM requiring internet to sign in, No Internet Access Due to VPN Kill Switch
I’m running a Windows 11 virtual machine in Hyper-V. I had been using this VM for a while without any issues, logging in with a local user account. However, after I linked a Microsoft account to the VM, during the next startup, it began requiring me to sign in with the Microsoft account.

The problem is that there is no active internet connection in the VM because I use Proton VPN with a kill switch enabled on the virtual machine, which blocks all network traffic. Now I’m stuck on the 'You'll need the Internet for this' screen and cannot proceed.
How can I bypass the Microsoft account login screen and return to using the local account, given that the VM has no internet access?"

Temporarily enable Internet on the host, login to VM, turn off MS Account, and back to your previous setup?

@Darius I made a mistake in my question: the kill switch is, of course, active on the virtual machine, and since I can't log in, I don't know how to disable the kill switch.

Try disabling or uninstalling the VPN service from safe mode? To get to safe mode: Restart the computer. At the sign-in screen, hold the Shift key down and then click Power > Restart.
After the computer restarts to the Choose an Option screen, select Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Startup Settings > Restart.
After the computer restarts, a list of options should appear. Select 4 or F4 to start the computer in Safe Mode.

What are the options when you do Cancel?

@YisroelTech returns to lock screen with user name and button "Sign in", when I press "Sign in" the form is shown once again

And there is only one sign in option, or it gives you other options there as well (like using the Password instead of the PIN)?

@YisroelTech immediately after clicking "Sign in" this window pops up

Can you try to see what it does if you disable the network for the VM altogether before booting it? Also what does it do if you boot to Safe Mode?
